# Smartsearch and tags

Tags: smartsearch

My joomla website has a number(100) of articles in a category named xyz.

How do i  add the name XYZ or text abc to every article in the category xyz?

The purpose of this is so that a public user can find/list all articles in category xyz by typing the term xyz or text abc  into smart search box.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to know? Please rephrase your post into a question, for example- how can I make my 100 articles searchable using smart search and the term xyz?......

Answer (score 1):

Edit each article and add the search term to the Meta Keywords under the Publishing tab.

Smart search indexes the Meta Keywords so searching on a search term using Smart Search will return all the relevant articles.